# Does the Pi Pico need any kind of shutdown switch?

Tags: power, pi-pico

I am using the Pico to monitor voltage and amperage outputs of some solar panels (gotta love science fair) and am concerned with possible data loss. Is there a chance for data loss if the Pico is suddenly disconnected from power (i.e. switching out the power supply)?

Answer (score 2):

The Pico may be arbitrarily powered down (switched off) without risk of damage to the Pico.

Comment: Just to clarify, this means I can disconnect it from power without doing anything other than removing the battery: no buttons or anything?

Comment: Yes, the Pico needs no special power off.